# How to use SUM DISTINCT when the order has the same qty of items

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, distinct, multiple-columns

I'm working on a query to show me total amount of orders sent and qty of items sent in a day. Due to the lots of joins I have duplicate rows. It looks like this:

```
 DispatchDate   Order   Qty 
   2019-07-02       1     2
   2019-07-02       1     2
   2019-07-02       1     2
   2019-07-02       2     2
   2019-07-02       2     2
   2019-07-02       2     2
   2019-07-02       3     5
   2019-07-02       3     5
   2019-07-02       3     5
```

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT DispatchDate, COUNT(DISTINCT Order), SUM(DISTINCT Qty)
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY DispatchDate
```

Obviously on this date there 3 orders with total of items that equals 9

However, the query is returning:

3 orders and 7 items

I don't have a clue how to resolve this issue. How can I sum the quantities for each orders instead of simply removing duplicates from only one column like SUM DISTINCT does

Comment: please share your expected result

Comment: Try `SUM(Qty)` ? You need to tell us what kind of result you expect here though because I don't understand what you're trying to do here with the Qty field.

Comment: Expected result would by 3 orders and 9 QTY. Using SUM(QTY) gives me 35 QTY and SUM(DISTINCT QTY) gives me 7 QTY.

Answer (score 1):

Could do a CTE

```
with cte1 as (
SELECT Order AS Order
    , DispatchDate
    , MAX(QTY) as QTY
FROM FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY Order
    , DispatchDate
)

SELECT DispatchDate
     , COUNT(Order)
     , SUM(Qty)
FROM cte1
GROUP BY DispatchDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You have major problems with your data model, if the data is stored this way.  If this is the case, you need a table with one row per *order*.

If this is the result of a query, you can probably fix the underlying query so you are not getting duplicates.

If you need to work with the data in this format, then extract a single row for each group.  I think that `row_number()` is quite appropriate for this purpose:

```
select count(*), sum(qty) 
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by dispatchdate, corder order by corder) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b865cecece50baa827ad593a2bf5ca6f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should avoid multiplicating of the rows while linking. Like, for example, using LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN. But, as we are where are:

```
SELECT    DispatchDate,  sum( Qty)
FROM (
SELECT distinct DispatchDate,  Order,  Qty
FROM TABLE1 )T
GROUP BY  DispatchDate
```

you have typed SUM(DISTINCT Qty), which summed up distinct values for Qty, that is 2 and 5. This is 7, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DispatchDate, COUNT(DISTINCT Order), SUM(DISTINCT Qty)
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY DispatchDate, Order
```

I think you need **dispatch date** and **order** wise sum of distinct quantity.

Answer (score 0):

> Due to the lots of joins I have duplicate rows.

IMHO, you should fix your primary data at first. Probably the `Qty` column is function of unique combination of `DispatchDate,Order` tuple. Delete duplicities in primary data source and ensure there cannot be different `Qty` for two rows with same `DispatchDate,Order`. Then go back to your task and you'll find your SQL much simpler. No offense regarding other answers but they just mask the mess in primary data source and are unclear about choosing `Qty` for duplicate `DispatchDate,Order` (some take max, some sum).

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Check comments within the code.

(I renamed the `order` column to `corder`; `order` can't be used as an identifier).

```
SQL> WITH test (dispatchdate, corder, qty)
  2       -- your sample data
  3       AS (SELECT DATE '2019-07-02', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4           SELECT DATE '2019-07-02', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5           SELECT DATE '2019-07-02', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6           --
  7           SELECT DATE '2019-07-02', 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8           SELECT DATE '2019-07-02', 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  9           SELECT DATE '2019-07-02', 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 10           --
 11           SELECT DATE '2019-07-02', 3, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 12           SELECT DATE '2019-07-02', 3, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 13           SELECT DATE '2019-07-02', 3, 5 FROM DUAL),
 14       -- compute sum of distinct qty per BOTH dispatchdate AND corder
 15       temp
 16       AS (  SELECT t1.dispatchdate,
 17                    t1.corder,
 18                    SUM (DISTINCT t1.qty) qty
 19               FROM test t1
 20           GROUP BY t1.dispatchdate,
 21                    t1.corder
 22          )
 23    -- the final result is then simple
 24    SELECT t.dispatchdate,
 25           COUNT (*) cnt,
 26           SUM (qty) qty
 27      FROM temp t
 28  GROUP BY t.dispatchdate;

DISPATCHDA        CNT        QTY
---------- ---------- ----------
02.07.2019          3          9

SQL>
```